# google cloud load balancing 503 Service Unavailable

Tags: google-cloud-platform, load-balancing

I am trying to perform a GET request to load balancer. If the request size is less than 2000 characters, the request succeeds. Otherwise I get error 503 'Service Unavailable'. Is this a bug in load balancer or is it a limitation?

Comment: Are you using curl? Does it work if you sent the same GET request directly to the instances behind the ELB?

Comment: No, I am not using curl and yes it works if I send the request directly to the instance

Comment: What type of Load Balancer? 

If its a HTTP(S) you can check the logs in the "Stackdriver->Logging->Logs" and see what is the real error you are getting, there are few "statusDetail" [1] that can help you narrow down the issue.

Also, make sure the instances are healthy and replying to the Health Check.

[1] - https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/#statusdetail_http_success_messages

Comment: If you already found a solution for your query, please post it as an 'answer'. This will help the other community members to get a benefit from it.